# In neovim, I don't want LSP warnings and errors to be displayed in noice

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I'm using neovim and so many plugins and all of them works correctly.

When cursor is on line which have warning or error, `echom a:message` command is execute.

Without noice plugin, it is not be problem. But I installed noice plugin and this command is executed repeatedly when cursor moving through row, which is negatively impacting performance.

So I don't want send this command when cursor on a row which has warning or error.

But I don't know which plugin (or neovim itself?) send this command.

Does anyone know solution?

neovim version: 0.9.1

installed plugins

- nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons
- nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua
- vim-airline/vim-airline
- vim-airline/vim-airline-themes
- joshdick/onedark.vim
- tomasiser/vim-code-dark
- tpope/vim-commentary
- airblade/vim-gitgutter
- petertriho/nvim-scrollbar
- kevinhwang91/nvim-hlslens
- vim-denops/denops.vim
- lfilho/cosco.vim
- tpope/vim-repeat
- nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter
- t9md/vim-quickhl
- windwp/nvim-autopairs
- jwalton512/vim-blade
- Shougo/ddu.vim
- Shougo/ddu-ui-ff
- Shougo/ddu-source-file_rec
- shun/ddu-source-buffer
- shun/ddu-source-rg
- Shougo/ddu-filter-matcher_substring
- Shougo/ddu-kind-file
- Shougo/ddc.vim
- Shougo/ddc-ui-native
- Shougo/ddc-source-around
- Shougo/ddc-matcher_head
- Shougo/ddc-sorter_rank
- Shougo/ddc-source-nvim-lsp
- j-hui/fidget.nvim
- dense-analysis/ale
- MunifTanjim/nui.nvim
- rcarriga/nvim-notify
- folke/noice.nvim
- neovim/nvim-lspconfig
- williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer

#### gif

[gif movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8nXW.gif)

I read nvim-lspconfig and noice document, I tried custom setting attach to lsp config, but cannnot solve problem.
And I cannot find methods which can solve this problem in document.

```
local custom_attach = function(_, bufnr)
    vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = vim.lsp.with(
      vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics, {
        -- disable virtual text
        virtual_text = false,

        -- show signs
        signs = true,

        -- delay update diagnostics
        update_in_insert = false,
      }
    )


nvim_lsp['gopls'].setup{
    on_attach = custom_attach,
    flags = {
      debounce_text_changes = 150,
      },
    settings = {gopls = {
    buildFlags =  {"-tags=js wasm"}
    }}
}
```

Comment: I found this command (echom a:message) is called by dein which is plugin manager.
But I cannot found option to disable message, and decided to change plugin manager to lazy.nvim.